# Incorrect datetime value : 'item.purchase_date'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
  SELECT depreciate.id, depreciate.item_id, depreciate.batch_code,
         new_item.description, depreciate.life_time, depreciate.scrap_value,
         depreciate.dep_type, item.po_number, item.purchase_value,
         item.current_value, item.purchase_date, depreciate.annual_depreciation,
         depreciate.depreciation_rate, depreciate.total_depreciate,
         depreciate.location, depreciate.dis_id 
    FROM depreciate, item, new_item 
   WHERE depreciate.item_id=item.item_id
     AND depreciate.item_id=new_item.id
     AND new_item.data_mining=1
     AND DATE_FORMAT('item.purchase_date', '%m %d') LIKE '%09-18%'
```

Please if someone can tell me the error of this code ? I'm new to this.

Comment: Errors are always reported back in MySQL.

Comment: His error is described in the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
AND DATE_FORMAT('item.purchase_date', '%m %d') LIKE '%09-18%'
```

to

```
HAVING DATE_FORMAT(`item`.`purchase_date`, '%m %d') LIKE '%09-18%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `'` when you are passing column name to the [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Try with:

```
... AND DATE_FORMAT(item.purchase_date, '%m %d') LIKE '%09-18%'
```